# Is there a way to define an helper function inside another one?

Tags: function, gdscript

This code raises a parsing error:

```
func foo():
 func bar():
   pass
 pass
```

`Error pasing expression, misplaced: func`

---

Is there a special keyword or other trick to define an inner function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in Godot 3.x. This is supported in Godot 4.0, with the given syntax. This was the proposal: ["Add lambda functions in GDScript"](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/2431).

**Addendum**: I should mention that the convention is that whatever stars with underscore ("_") is to be considered private. And accessing them externally is at your own risk. *This approach has worked well for Python for a long time*.

*There are some things you can do…*

---

### "Private" field

As you would know, you can use `setget` to have getters and setters which will run every time you access a field externally, or using `self`. Well, you can write getters and setter that just fail.

For example:

```
var _value setget noset, noget

func noset(_new_value):
    push_error("Invalid access.")

func noget():
    push_error("Invalid access.")
```

This results in an error when used from another script. Also results in an error when used from the same script with `self._value`, but not using `_value` from the same script (without self). Thus we have a "private" field.

Similarly, by only specifying the setter, we can have a readonly property:

```
var value setget noset

func noset(_new_value):
    push_error("Invalid access.")
```

---

### "Private" method

Following the same idea, we can store a token in a private field. And use it as access check. We will use a new object, so that it is impossible match it by chance. *This is similar to having a monitor (as understood in threading), holding the lock, and doing try_enter… Except without the threading part.*

```
var _token setget noset, noget

func noset(_new_value):
    push_error("Invalid access.")

func noget():
    push_error("Invalid access.")

func _method(token):
    if token != _token: # try enter
        push_error("Invalid access") # did fail to enter
        return

    # did enter
    pass

func _init():
    _token = ClassDB.instance("Object") # hold lock
```

From the same script, you have access to `_token`. Thus, you can call the method like this:

```
_method(_token)
```

However, `_token` is "private", and passing anything else will result in an error. Thus, it will not be possible to use the method from another script.

*This is an improved version of [a comment by me2beats](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/641#issuecomment-699579606). On the proposal ["Add public/private access modifiers to GDScript and autocompletion improvements"](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/641).*

---

### Evaluate code

Something else you can do is create a script in from code (think "eval"). This is done with the [`GDScript`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_gdscript.html) class.

You can create your script like this:

```
var script = GDScript.new()
script.source_code = "func run():print('hello world')" # create code at runtime
script.reload()
```

Instantiate it like this:

```
var script_instance = script.new()
```

*And, of course, you could hold the instance in a "private" field. You might also be interested in [`FuncRef`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_funcref.html).*

Then use whatever you declared in there, in this case the `run` function:

```
script_instance.call("run")
```

See [`call`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-call), [`get`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#id1), [`set`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#id4).

---

If you don't to create code at runtime, you might instead load a script with `load`. Or use an [Inner class](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#inner-classes).

If you don't need a whole script, you might use [`Expression`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_expression.html) instead.